# Как избежать дублирования в Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, дублирование

Пишу приложение по подсчету калорий, используя React-Redux. У меня есть 4 графы на главной странице (Завтрак, Обед, Ужин и Перекус). В данный момент у меня имеется 4 редьюсера для каждого приема пищи и вся информация в файлах дублируется. Вот как сейчас выглядит архетиктура Redux: [image]
Я понимаю, что это неверный подход, но пока не могу найти способ сократить код и сделать его менее нагруженным. Вот пример того, как расписан мой редьюсер для Завтрака. Точно такой же код в файле остальных редьюсеров, меняется только название приемов пищи [image: Такой код повторяется и для остальных файлов]

**Как я вижу решение проблемы:**
Возможно, стоит создать в одном редьюсере InitialState с массивами данных, вот так:

```
let initialState = {
       breakfast: [],
       lunch: [],
       dinner: [],
}
```

но и в таком случае у меня будет много повторяющегося кода для добавления, удаления и редактирования продуктов в редьюсере. Как можно избежать этой проблемы?
Надеюсь я понятно изложила свою проблему.

Comment: Какого именно дублирования вы хотитет избежать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от того, как вы дальше будете использовать приложение. Есть два пути:

1. Например, вы действительно будете по-разному обрабатывать разные приемы пищи. И у вас появятся совершенно разные данные внутри `breakfastProducts`, `dinnerProducts` и т.д.
   При таком подходе дублирование кода вполне себе оправдано. Потому что это разные сущности с точки зрения бизнеса. И даже если сейчас у них поведение одинаковое, это не значит, что оно будет таким в ближайшем будущем. При таком подходе вы имеете полностью независисые сущности, которые управляются в одном месте. Единственное, что я бы предложил тогда, это не плодить множество файлов, а описывать все в файле `ducks.js`
   Примером такого файла может послужить такой код:

```js
export const FETCH_SOMETHING_START = 'something/FETCH_SOMETHING_START';
const FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESS = 'something/FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESS';
const FETCH_SOMETHING_REJECT = 'something/FETCH_SOMETHING_REJECT';

export const fetchUserStart = () => ({
  type: FETCH_SOMETHING_START,
});

export const fetchUserSuccess = (payload = {}) => ({
  type: FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESS,
  payload,
});

export const fetchUserReject = payload => ({
  type: FETCH_SOMETHING_REJECT,
  payload,
});

export const initialState = {
  isLoading: true,
  error: null,
  data: [],
};

export const somethingReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case FETCH_SOMETHING_START:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, error: null };
    case FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        data: payload,
      };
    case FETCH_SOMETHING_REJECT:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, error: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Вся логика, связанная с редьюсером крутится в одном файле. Здесь и константы, и экшен креаторы. Более оправдано, как по мне, но слегка вкусовщина.

2. Возможно, у вас действительно всегда будет одна и таже логика для продуктов завтрака, ужина и обеда. Тогда смысла хранить их в отдельных стейтах нет. Вы можете хранить просто продукты. Ваш стейт будет выглядить так:

```js
const state = {
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
  products: [
    {
      productName: '',
      fat: ''
      PRODUCT_TYPE: ''
    }

  ]
}
```

Обратите внимание, я специально ввел еще одно поле `PRODUCT_TYPE` - в котором вы можете хранить к какому типу относится продукту. К завтраку, ужину или обеду.
А потом уже взаимодействовать с селекторами (при помощи reselect), то есть фильтровать по типу примерно таким образом:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const productsSelector = state => state.products; // здесь еще зависит от того, как в mainReducer вы записали.
export const breakfastProducts = createSelector(
  productsSelector,
  products => products.filter(item => item.PRODUCT_TYPE === 'breakfast')
)
```

И тогда вы полностью избежите дублирования. Но это предполагает, что и работать вы будете со всеми продуктами одинаково. Все зависит от поставленных задач.